# DRV8825 Stepper Driver Burning Up

Tags: arduino, prototyping, stepper-driver, protoboard

I am trying to wire up 3 [NEMA 23 Steppers](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/cui-devices/NEMA23-31-01SD-AMT112S/9477647) driven by 3 [DRV8825 drivers](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/pololu-corporation/2987/10450470) and an [Arduino Due](https://store.arduino.cc/usa/due). I tried to solder a perfboard prototype, but when I turned it on the first board burned and the ground jumper (red wire at the top in the picture below) started smoking.

I had this issue before when I wired one driver on a breadboard. I fixed this by powering the driver with an adjustable DC power supply, and making sure that worked before switching back to the 24V DC power supply. This time, I successfully tested the setup with 3 drivers on a breadboard with the 24V supply, and set the current limiting potentiometer to the correct value (all less than 1.6 A).

I took the same setup and transferred it to the perfboard. I checked for shorts by testing for continuity with a multimeter. The one thing I did not do is test the perfboard with the adjustable power supply (oversight on my part).

I am definitely an electronics amateur, so I may be missing something obvious. Why do I keep on frying boards? Some things that I think could be the problem:

- I need 3 capacitors instead of 1, and I need them closer to the drivers.
- Bad power supply.

I made a wiring diagram of the setup, and took pictures of the perfboard below.

[image: Wiring Diagram]

[image: Perfboard Front]

[image: Perfboard Back]

Comment: Need to have the stepper motors attached before powering the ICs. https://youtu.be/OfyT1xTZC6o

Answer (score 1):

First of all let me note something: I do not trust theese little ICs for driving my steppers. If you look at the [datasheet of the  NEMA 23 steppers](https://www.cuidevices.com/product/resource/nema23-amt112s.pdf), you will see some graphs indicating the current needed to operate the coils inside the steppers:

[image: datasheet pic]

is 1.4 Amps per phase is too much for your [DRV8825 stepper driver](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8825.pdf?ts=1618161648101&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F), even though its datasheet says it can carry 2.5A, you need to get a bigger/stronger stepper driver. I had a issue where my stepper drivers got burned twice because they were not strong enough for the currents they needed to handle.

So I think its really likely your ICs (or one of them) burned already, creating a short and drawing current constantly, overheating the wire untill it melts.

I recommend connecting only one IC, with one stepper, see if it works, then move to soldering the second one.

Use thicker wires if possible.

Do not forget to clean your board after soldering, using isopropanol. Flux leftover on your pcb will conduct, leading in shorts.

When soldering, try to use lower temperature so that you wont fry your IC while soldering.

Also, I would recommend using female header pins on the pcb in place of the driver ICs

[image: female header pins]

And then place your ICs on the headers. That way, you wont have to solder directly on the IC, and you will be able to remove/replace the IC.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That's a bit disappointing that I may need a beefier driver. I switched to drivers I have on hand that look like TB6600 drivers. They work without a problem. The only complaint I have is that I can't change the microstepping settings through code (to change from rough to fine stepping), but that's easy enough to work around. I will try to implement the recommendations you made. I definitely forgot to clean the board with IPA.

Comment: Such delicate circuits requires big enough, ceramic power bypass capacitors, placed as close to IC as possible. Tantalum caps in parallel also increase reliability. Failure is often caused by spikes in power lines caused by self-inductance in motor winding, especially in fast-decay mode, which leads to "latching" inside IC and burning, or over-voltage and also burning.